# Remote connect to WAMP MySQL not connecting

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I am running a website on Windows Server 2016, using WAMP. The site has a mysql database which I have add users with password and given static IP's and %

Everytime I try and connect using the php string I get error as follow

> Warning: mysql_connect(): Can't connect to MySQL server on
>   '***.***.***.***' (13) Cannot Connect

When I use MySQL Workbench I can log in no problem to the MySQL DB

I am currently using the following code

```
$host="***.***.***.***"; // Host IP Address I even tried it by :3306 port after IP
$username="***"; // Mysql username 
$password="***"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="gs"; // Database name 

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
```

I have added to phpmyadmin.conf file the following as well

```
Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.0.4/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    AllowOverride all
    Order Allow,Deny 
    Allow from all
    Allow from 0.0.0.0
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

It is denying me access any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

I have used mysqli as well this is the error I am receiving and here is my code

```
$servername = "154.0.***.***";
$username = "***";
$password = "***";
$port = "3306";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $port);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
```

> Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): Permission denied in
>   /home/www/e-track.biz on line 30 Connection failed: Permission denied

Line 30 is

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $port);
```

Comment: Is your MySQL user allowed to run from outside the localhost ?

Comment: What says the mysql command `SHOW GRANTS $username` on your mysql server ?

Comment: The username has % in it and I have tried giving the external server IP as allowed as well

Comment: I would say firewall problem but it seems that MySQL respond and just says taht your user is not allowed...Does the password for the user is right (I'm sure you have check this but...)

Comment: I have turned off firewall, allowed 3306 port username is correct password correct

Comment: And if you try the code on your server directly ?

Comment: On the same server it allows connection, just confirmed that but using different IP to connect to it denies connection

Comment: Beside the username allowed just for localhost (which is not I know)...you are not using VPN or proxy on your remote computer (stupid I know...but sometime)

Comment: No VPN or proxy, just wamp server. I have even tried changing apache according to some sites altered the phpmyadmin.conf file as well still no luck

Comment: NOTE: phpMyAdmin has NOTHING to do with MySQL. Its a tool written in PHP much like any other application. It does not control access to a MySQL database. However, the changes you made to it will allow anyone in the universe to use it, and delete your databases

Comment: Parameter 4 of `mysqli()` should be a Database Name and NOT a port number

Comment: Also it looks like you are using a very old version of WAMPSevrer

Answer (score 0):

Hi,

Please use below code:- if this code will not work then please check the server setting.

```
<?php 
$servername = "154.0.***.***";
$username = "***";
$password = "***";
$db_name="gs";

$con = @mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password,$db_name);
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Database connection error: ".mysqli_connect_error();
}
else
{
    echo "Connected successfully";
}
?>
```

Comment: Database connection error: Permission denied, by server settings would you think Apache or phpmyadmin, I am running windows server doubt I am being blocked from there?

Comment: Go to Server Setting -> Database -> User Management -> click on database user -> change "Access control" as "Allow remote connections from any host" then Apply and OK. on the server.

Comment: Cannot find those settings on Windows Server 2017 Standard

Comment: In which Hosting Panel do you have. You have hosting panel in godaddy or other.

Comment: I am hosting domain at godaddy, it is set to the IP address, it connects to the IP but my server takes it to one page only

Comment: can you connect me with teamviewer. show that  i can see your database settings.